# Interfacing with VBA application

Tags: c++, mfc, com, atl

Which one is easier to interface C++ with an application written in VBA via COM (type library file), ATL or MFC? Could you please provide material to study?

Comment: Although I am not sure what ATL or MFC is, the method I used was to create a DLL in C++ where you expose functions using a DEF file. In your VBA application, you can load the DLL, and use these functions...

Answer (score 2):

To use external COM objects from C++, use the compiler COM support, via `#import`. It's by far the easiest and most comprehensive.

- `#import` documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx

To create COM objects to expose functionality written in C++ to VBA, use ATL. Note in this scenario you should use Dual interfaces.

- ATL dual interfaces howto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff8baszx.aspx
- Defining interfaces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690150(v=vs.85).aspx